# What do the terms root, bootloader unlock, custom recovery and ROM installation mean?

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, rom, bootloader-lock

I'm trying to root my Galaxy Note 4 and I see the above terms being used everywhere. What do each of them mean? I have a vague idea about each of them, but I'm still confused about some of them.
A brief description about each would be enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use search function of this site

Comment: The answers to such a question reminds me of [bike-shed effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Term `Rooting` in android means to  gain super user access(Administrator access) for which root access is requires as the `su` binary should be installed to `/system` partition.

This is usually done via a `Recovery`.Every android phone have a in-built recovery which can generally only flash OTA updates and ROM's provided by the device’s manufacturer. So a `custom recovery` like CWM,TWRP etc is installed.A custom recovery has more features and allows you to flash any suppoerted file.

Each android device has a bootloader which is something like BIOS in PC.And many phones comes with locked bootloader which prevents users from installing any other ROM. Hence unlocking bootloader is a common term related to rooted devices.

`ROM` stands for Read Only Memory. A custom ROM replaces your device's Android operating system normally stored in read-only memory with a Different OS. Installation of Custom Rom is the process of flashing a Custom ROM usually using a Custom Recovery/ADB

Answer (score 0):

`Root` - means having "superuser" or administrator access to the OS.

`Bootloader unlock` - means allowing the device to boot a custom OS.

`Custom recovery` - allows you to make a complete backup of the internal storage as well as flash ZIPs.

`ROM installation` - is actual process of installing a custom OS.